# Eliminar outlier en grafico tipo violín

Tags: r

Me gustaría hacer un grafico tipo "violín" pero que este no tenga en cuenta los outlier.

¿Qué tengo que añadir en el código para no tener en cuenta los outlier?

```
iris[1,1]<-20
iris[112,1]<-12
iris[86,1]<- -4

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_violin(alpha=0.9)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estrictamente no son outliers, como sería el caso de un boxplot. Son puntos en los que hay densidad. Por `help(geom_violin)` no hay un argumento para no graficar outliers, como sí lo hay en `geom_boxplot()`. Me parece que la única forma es eliminarlos de los datos o pasarlos a NA. Cómo los elimines dependerá de tu definición de outlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya te lo comentó mpaladino, el concepto de outlier no existe en las gráficas de violín, tal como en los boxplots. Para eliminar los valores atípicos de la gráfica, en realidad lo que debes hacer, es eliminarlos de los datos, por lo que, en primer lugar deberías definir el criterio por el cual considerar un valor como atípico. Si quisieras aplicar un criterio similar al de los boxplots, podrías utilizar [`boxplot.stats()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.6.2/topics/boxplot.stats), por ejemplo:

```
iris[1,1]<-20
iris[112,1]<-12
iris[86,1]<- -4
 
boxplot.stats(iris$Sepal.Length)$out
[1] 20 -4 12
```

Y finalmente:

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  mutate(is_outlier = Sepal.Length %in% boxplot.stats(iris$Sepal.Length)$out) %>% 
  filter(!is_outlier) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_violin(alpha=0.9)
```